# SockJS fails to create/connect to Spring WebSocket

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am learning Spring WebSocket. I have successfully run this [Spring WebSocket](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) tutorial. Now I am trying to incorporate it *as-is* in my existing Spring MVC application. When I run it from Chrome browser, I see below error in its dev console.

**Chrome Console**

```
Opening Web Socket...
GET http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket/info?t=1497735312528 500 (Internal Server Error) -- abstract-xhr.js:132
Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket -- stomp.min.js:8
```

**Server Side Error**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket/info' in servlet with name 'MyAppName'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
```

**Client Side**

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

**Server Side**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I have tried to solve this for couple hours now. How do I resolve this?

ty

Comment: Did you solve it? I see mt have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If your application context is `MyAppName` then you don't need to specify it in the `addEndpoint` method - this path is relative to your aaplication context.

Probably `registry.addEndpoint("/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket")` registers the endpoint with path `/MyAppName/MyAppName/api/gs-guide-websocket`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, mine example will hint the problem

My application base URL
http://localhost:8080/socket/

My js file

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/socket/greeting');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({name: 'test'}, function(frame) {
        
        console.log("session Id:" + socket._transport.url); 
        console.log("user Id:" + socket.current_user_id);
        console.log("socket Id:" + stompClient.id);
        var sessionId = /\/([^\/]+)\/websocket/.exec(socket._transport.url)[1];
        $("#fname").val(sessionId);
        console.log("socket Id:" + sessionId);
        stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/errors", function(message) {
            alert("Error " + message.body);
        });

        stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", function(message) {
            showGreeting(message.body);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert("STOMP error " + error);
    });
}
```

My socket configuration

```
package com.connectips.socket.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

import com.connectips.socket.interceptor.HttpHandshakeInterceptor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/greeting").addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
    }
}
```